# Cancel Google API request

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, google-api

Is it possible to abort a Google API request? Something like:

```
req = gapi.client.request({
   path: 'youtube/v3/search',
   params: {
        q: search_query,
        type: 'video',
        part: 'id,snippet',
        maxResults: 8,
        fields: 'items(id(videoId),snippet(thumbnails,title))'
})
req.execute(function(result){ console.log(result) })
```

And then later (before the request returned)

```
req.abort()
```

Comment: If it uses XMLHttpRequest under the hood, you should be able to, right?

Comment: In theory. I just started using jQuery ajax requests instead since it's a really simple API. But I'd like to know if there is a way to do it using google's client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did this by simply building the XMLHttpRequest's by hand (with jQuery). It was remarkably easy.

```
window.current_search = $.ajax('https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        q: search_query,
        type: 'video',
        part: 'id,snippet',
        maxResults: 8,
        fields: 'items(id(videoId),snippet(thumbnails,title))',
        key: apiKey
    }
}).done(render_page)
```

And if I need to cancel a request...

```
window.current_search.abort()
```

The code isn't even noticeably longer than the version utilizing the api.